# AngularJS repeatedly auto click button after first initial click

Tags: html, angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to create a scenario where after a user first clicks a button attached to an ng-click directive, the button then will automatically and repeatedly be clicked until it is disabled by and ng-disabled directive.  The code for the button is attached.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" id = "getIt"
    ng-click = "runoutIteration(totalAssy,subsetForecast,a,totalAssy,rawConsumption,totalRawParts,master.raw)" ng-disabled = "checked" >Decrement</button>
```

Comment: you can call the function recursively until `checked` is true.For that you need to pass `checked` as parameter . Will this solve your problem.

Comment: And take care to don't lock the browser with those recursive calls.